# JQuery select first of type between two types

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find a **selector** to select first of type between two tags where a third tag exists. For example:

```
<div></div>
<video></video>
<img>
```

or any mix of order.

I would like to select first occurrence of `<video>` OR `<img>` tag. In this case, the `video` tag will be selected. But if:

```
<img>
<div></div>
<video></video>
```

Then `<img>` will be selected. But `<div>` will never get selected.

Answer (score 4):

`$('img, video').first()` will select first `img` or `video`

Answer (score 0):

This will select both and use the fiirst one:

```
$("div, video")[0]
```

This is easy to adapt for selecting the second element:

```
$("div, video")[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery:

```js
let res = document.querySelectorAll('img, video')[0];
console.log(res);
```

```html
<div></div>
<video></video>
<img>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it using jQuery implying to wrap your tags into a... wrapper :

```js
var validTags = ['img', 'video'];

function getFirstValidTag (wrapper) {
  return $('#' + wrapper).children(validTags.join(', '))[0];
}

console.log(getFirstValidTag('wrapper-1'));
console.log(getFirstValidTag('wrapper-2'));
console.log(getFirstValidTag('wrapper-3'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper-1">
  <div></div>
  <img src="" alt="" />
  <video></video>
</div>

<div id="wrapper-2">
  <img src="" alt="" />
  <div></div>
  <video></video>
</div>

<div id="wrapper-3">
  <video></video>
  <div></div>
  <img src="" alt="" />
</div>
```